# How to use slicebox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get slicebox to work in a test page. From the documentation, it seems I needed to use the slicebox css file and have a jquery script linked up along with slicebox.js. From there, I thought it was as simple as calling the function in the script as in "$('#sb-slider').slicebox(); But the pictures do not even show up.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <title>Slicebox Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slicebox.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="sb-slider" class="sb-slider">
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/strupler/2969141180" target="_blank"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="image1"/></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/strupler/2968268187" target="_blank"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="image2"/></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/strupler/2968114825" target="_blank"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="image1"/></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/strupler/2968122059" target="_blank"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="image1"/></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/strupler/2969119944" target="_blank"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="image1"/></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/strupler/2968126177" target="_blank"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="image1"/></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/strupler/2968945158" target="_blank"><img src="images/7.jpg" alt="image1"/></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div>
        <a href="#">Next</a>
        <a href="#">Previous</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.slicebox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $("#sb-slider").slicebox();
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to also link the included modernizer script in there.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/modernizr.custom.46884.js"></script>
```

I have it working but not in all browsers/platforms.

Comment: I got it fully working now, all browsers.  Some have to use the graceful degrade however.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the css and the js in this folders?
css/slicebox.css
js/jquery.slicebox.js
Maybe that is the problem. You have to download and put that in that folder

Answer (score 0):

You do need to add a ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sb-slider").slicebox();
});
```

Comment: I added that, but the issue still persists in that none of my images show up. I don't know if this plugin is dependent on some other CSS file I am unaware of, because if I take out the class="sb-slider" the images appear but obviously without the effects.

Comment: Firebug doesn't seem to think so.